# sub CPT and CRUD

Tags: custom-post-types

I need to create a child CPT for a parent CPT and display CRUD for the child CPT in a metabox of the parent CPT 'create post page'.

For example: Suppose a vendor have different products. I need to display related product CRUD feature right under VENDOR creation page in a metabox.

I don't want to use any plugin. Is there any wp way to do it?

I can create hidden post type + meta and display them in metabox. Mostly I need the CRUD functionality like wordpress's ***view all post*** page.

Can you please give me some hints?